# ext4 recovery: superblock backup numbers

Tags: linux, ext4

Good time of day!

After a horrible failure of the HDD, I got myself in a situation where I cannot mount the disk - it complains about the superblock issues. I found a great article that describes how to restore superblock from a backup. When I run:

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdd1
```

I get:

```
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208
```

So I can recover it using this command:

```
e2fsck -b block_number /dev/sdd1
```

But what "block_number" should I use? And what do those numbers in the output of the previous command mean? Are those different backups done at a different time? Does this mean the higher the number is, the more recent version it is? Or there is a ring buffer?..

Thanks!

John.

Comment: AFAIK all of them are the same, so you can iterate through them and find the first one that works.